# How to see the list of tables that I have created in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new learner of database system.currently I am trying to learn `sql` commands and related tasks.

I have created some tables in sql. Now, I want to see the list of all tables that I have created. What command should I use?

I am using `oracle`.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: What database are you using ? The command is definitely available, but the syntax will change depending on the exact database engine.

Comment: I am using oracle

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT * from USER_TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL and SQL based DB such as hive you can use

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

and to view details of table you can use

```
show create table <table-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the below command:

```
select * from cat;
```